# Execution time of same code in onactionexecuting vs onactionexecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a base controller with the method `OnActionExecuted` which has some code.

I want to move that filter checking on the method `OnActionExecuting`.

Will the change provide any performance issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, (regardless of performance) you should use the [method that is appropriate to your situation](http://forums.asp.net/t/2062472.aspx?Difference%20between%20OnActionExecuted%20and%20OnActionExecuting).  If you want execution to be performed before the execution of the action method then use `OnActionExecuting`.  If you want execution to be performed after the execution of the action then use `OnActionExecuted`.

As for performance, they should both be exactly the same.  The controller offers two empty virtual methods for you to implement in your own controller (no performance concerns here):

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
}

protected virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
}
```

If you look at the [MVC source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) (see code sample below) you can see the `ControllerActionInvoker` simply calls the `OnActionExecuting(preContext)` method before invoking the action and then calls the `OnActionExecuted(postContext)` after the action is complete (or if an exception was thrown):

```
internal static ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation)
{
    filter.OnActionExecuting(preContext);
    ...

    try
    {
        postContext = continuation();
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        ...
        filter.OnActionExecuted(postContext);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
        filter.OnActionExecuted(postContext);
        if (!postContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    if (!wasError)
    {
        filter.OnActionExecuted(postContext);
    }
    return postContext;
}
```

I believe the `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` methods will be called regardless, even if it is the empty (non-overridden) methods being called so performance should not be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's just a metter of when the operations are executed: before or after the action method is invoked